# Incompatible key type Set<String> for Map<String,String> at line 23 column 6

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am practicing salesforce and stuck with an error. Can someone help me out?

Error:

> Incompatible key type Set for Map at line 23 column 6

Apex Class:

```apex
public class mapapex {
    public map<string,string> mst;
    public list<string> lst {get;set;}
    public set<string> str  {get;set;}
    public set<string> mod {get;set;}
    public list<string> s{get;set;};
    public mapapex(){
       mst= new map<string,string>();
       mst.put('India','rupee');
       mst.put('USA','Doller');
       mst.put('Japan','yen');  
    }
    public pagereference showkey(){
       str=mst.keyset();
       return null;
    }
    public pagereference showvalue(){
        lst=mst.values();
       return null;
    }
    public pagereference showmod(){
        s = mst.get(mod);
        return null;
    }        
}
```

VF Page:

```visualforce
<apex:page controller="mapapex" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:commandButton value="showkeys" action="{!showkey}" rerender="one"/>
            <apex:dataList id="one" value="{!str}" var="a"> {!a} </apex:dataList>
            <apex:commandButton value="showvalue" action="{!showvalue}" rerender="two"/>
            <apex:dataList id="two" value="{!lst}" var="b"> {!b} </apex:dataList>
            <apex:outputlabel> Enter the value for key- India </apex:outputlable>
            <apex:inputText value="{!mod}"/>
            <apex:outputlabel> Value for key India is {!s}</apex:outputlable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `mod` in your controller to be a `Set`. And it looks like in your page you are trying to pass in a `String`.

Change:

```apex
public set<string> mod {get;set;}
```

To:

```apex
public String mod {get;set;}
```

Comment: Hi Jesse..I have updated the code..could you please advice if you solutions still works with this update.

Comment: @YusufSyed Did you change what I pointed out? There may be other issues in the code, I was simply answering why you are getting an `Incompatible key type` error. As, that was your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do few changes

1. Modify the declaration of

```apex
public set<string> mod {get;set;}
public list<string> s{get;set;}
```

to

```apex
public string mod {get;set;}
public string s{get;set;}
```

because those are actually string variables and not collection as your intention is to get the mod from user input as key and get the corresponding value from the map.

2. In your VF page, there is no code to invoke the `showmod()` method. So modify

```visualforce
<apex:outputlabel> Value for key India is {!s}</apex:outputlabel>
```

to

```visualforce
<apex:outputlabel id="three"> Value for key India is {!s}</apex:outputlabel>
```

and add

```visualforce
<apex:commandButton value="showmod" action="{!showmod}" rerender="three"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh...Though i did't represent my problem and purpose here in a good way..you got what my intention was with this code..thank you.

Comment: Welcome Yousuf. Is there anything I could be of help?

Comment: Thanks Vignesh... no as of now...will post if needed.

Comment: If the provided solution solved your issue please mark it as answer so that others with same issue gets benefited.

Answer (score 1):

@Yusuf, There is also need to change in the following line:

Change:

```
s = mst.get(mod);
```

To:

```
s.add(mst.get(mod));
```